# How does pv work?

Tags: pipe, tar, pv

How does the following command work?

```
pv file.tar.gz | tar -xz
```

From my understanding the pipe operator `|` creates a `pipe` and `stdout` of `pv` is mapped to the `O_WRONLY` end of the pipe and `tar`'s `stdin` is mapped to the `O_RDONLY` with both `O_WRONLY` and `O_RDONLY` existing in `pipefs`

This is all well and good, but the following is being printed to my screen:

```
31.1MiB 0:00:05 [6.17MiB/s] [===================================>] 100%
```

To the best of my knowledge this progress bar is not generated by `tar` because it would be available via an option if it was and I wouldn't need `pv`, thus `pv` has to be generating it. But how?  `pv`'s `stdout` is mapped to `O_WRONLY`.

I also read that some shells use *socket pairs* for pipes in place of `pipefs` and *socket pairs* are bidirectional. But that just seems like it would tie up `stdin` and `stdout` of both commands until one or both completes. which is not the case in the above example since the progress bar updates in real time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The progress bar is a feature of `pv`, it is written on standard error. From the `pv` manual:

> pv shows the progress of data through a pipeline by giving information
>          such as time elapsed, percentage completed (with progress bar), current
>          throughput rate, total data transferred, and ETA.
>
> To use it, insert it in a pipeline between two processes, with the
>          appropriate options.  Its standard input will be passed through to its
>          standard output and progress will be shown on standard error.

There is really no problem writing to the TTY while at the same time redirecting both standard output and standard error though:

```
$ ( echo "out"; echo "error" >&2; echo "hi there" >$(tty) ) 2>&1 | cat >file
hi there

$ cat file
out
error
```

Also, `O_WRONLY` and `O_RDONLY` are not nouns but adjectives. Standard output is write-only and standard input is read-only.